# How to find second peak of continuous function?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to write a function that reliably finds the first and second peak of a an array. A solution for a 1D array is enough, but if the solution works for 2D, that would be a bonus.

Here's an example:

```
ar = np.array([1,2,3,4,4.5,4.1,4.05,4,3,2,1,2,3,3.5,3.2,2,1,0])
indices = np.arange(len(ar))

ar2 = np.array([1,2,3,4,4.5,4.1,4.2,4,3,2,1,2,3,3.5,3.2,2,1,0])
indices2 = np.arange(len(ar2))
```

I want a `peak(arr, tolerance)` function that can take an array and give the first and second peaks. For `ar`, it will be `4.5` and `3.5` at `indices` `4` and `13`.

Now I also want the function to be tolerant to small noise. It should give the same result for `ar2` even though technically the second mode is `4.2` at `indices2 = 6`. Perhaps the function can have a fault tolerance parameter either in terms of `ar` or `indices`.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code for the 1D modes

Comment: Calling these "modes" is potentially confusing.  In statistics, the [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) is the most frequently occurring element, so `mode(ar)` would be 2.  It looks like you want the values and locations of the peaks in the array.  Take a look at [`scipy.signal.find_peaks`](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html).

Comment: Thanks @WarrenWeckesser, this looks exactly like the tool I need!

Comment: I called it mode because the actual application is to find the modes of histograms, but indeed for the problem I've shown, it is peaks that I want to find.